# im having syntax issues pulling data from 6 text boxes with identical names (other than a number at the end) in a for loop

Tags: vb.net

I have 6 different text boxes with similar names:

```
txtBox1, txtBox2....txtBox6
```

I also have an array:

```
dim intValue (0 to 5) as Integer
```

Now I want to use a for loop to assign the value in each text box to a corresponding space in the array, concatenating the value of the loop counter with the string "txtBox" and retrieving the data using the *.text* method.

here is my code:

```
 For count As Integer = 0 To 5
            Dim strCount As String = count
            Dim strTxtBox As String = "txtBox" & strCount
            intValues(count) = Convert.toInt32(strTxtBox.Text)
        Next
```

the issue is that the string name doesn't point to txtBox1, txtBox 2 etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the control name, you have to use the property "Name".

You should try something like that:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        For Each c As Control In Controls
            If c.Name = "txtBox" & i Then
                intValue(i) = Convert.ToInt32(c.Text)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
```

The above code is just an example, but it should work for you.
Anyway you can write a better code checking the type of the control or maybe using a different loop logic, but the basic idea is that if you want to use in your code the name od the control you have to use the NAME property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Im using vb as a code-behind for an ASP.net app and I get the following error:

    'Name' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Comment: @Glenncito Cast `c` to a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` using `DirectCast`, then you will have access to these properties (`.Name` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`strTxtBox` is a string, nothing more.  You cannot refer to control names by String without special code.  Rather than go down that path, I'd create an array and populate it with text boxes:

```
Dim txtBoxes As TextBox() = {txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3, txtBox4, txtBox5, txtBox6}
Dim intValues As Integer(0 To 5)
For count As Integer = 0 To 5
    intValues(count) = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxes(count).Text)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate through the contents of `Controls` to find the textboxes.  You can either:

- Use the `.Tag` property to label textboxes to identify them, or as the other answer points out, use the `.Name` property.
- If you have a lot of other controls on the form, and they may not be in order, you could also check each control to see if it's a textbox. Assume they are in reverse order, as the `Controls` array goes from end to beginning.

  ```
  Dim nums() As Integer = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
  Dim ctrl As Control
  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf (ctrl) Is TextBox Then
          ctrl.Text = nums(Val(ctrl.Name(ctrl.Name.Length - 1)) - 1)
      End If
  Next
  ```

You could also instantiate an array of textboxes programmatically, but you'd have to set all of the placement, etc. by hand.

As I commented on the answer below, you may need to cast the `ctrl` to a `System.Web.UI.Control` to access the `.Name`, using [DirectCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).